# Access 2016: Form shows now results when using a query parameter from included ComboBox

Tags: forms, parameters, ms-access-2016

I'm banging my head against a wall trying to solve something I'm sure is simple. I'm using Access 2016 and trying to build a form which essentially has a filter combo box in the header.

Let's say the form is called myForm and the comboBox cboStatus. The query contains a field called status.

In my query, I basically have SELECT * FROM myQuery WHERE [myQuery].[status]=[Forms]![myForm]![cboStatus]. Eventually, I intend to add a VBA-based event on the COmboBox to update the query when it changes, but for now, I select a value and hit Refresh All on the form, just to test it.

No matter what value I have in the ComboBox, no records display in the form. What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If `status` is a text field then you need

```
SELECT * FROM myQuery WHERE [myQuery].[status]= "'" & [Forms]![myForm]![cboStatus] & "'"
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to do it, in fact it makes it worse in some ways.  Previously, if I had a value set in the comboBox in the form (let's say "complete"), it would show only rows with status "complete" if I opened the query. It was just in the form itself that no results showed. If I add in the quote marks, neither the query nor the form shows any results. The status is a string variable, FYI.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved it! I didn't define the form element (comboBox) as a parameter in the SQL query. Adding:

```
PARAMETERS [Forms]![myForm]![cboStatus] Text ( 255 );
```

seems to have fixed it! Wanted to make sure I responded in case anyone else has the same issue!